# Ubuntu 14.04 server PBIS and Samba - SMB drops domain

Tags: 14.04, samba, xserver, domain-server

I have been working on this for a while and keep running into issues. I used PBIS to domain the machine on my domain, but ran into an issue with the version of Samba that comes with Ubuntu. I downgraded to sernet-samba, so I could use PBIS and install the requirements with it.

I am still getting password errors, after reviewing the system logs I notice that when i try to connect to the server, the domain drop,s, then says my username can not be verified. After a while the sys log will say "Domain is now online".

Line of the system log
lsass: [lsass] Domain 'domain name' is now offline
lsass: [lsass] Failed to authenticate user (name = 'username') -> error = 40121, symbol = LW_ERROR_DOMAIN_IS_OFFLINE